# Cloudformation append to stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have an AWS stack with lambda and api gateway resources.  There are about 250 resources and cloudformation only allows uploading 200 at a time so I split it into 2 templates.  However when I run the deploy commands for each stack like so

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template.yml --stack-name my-stack --region us-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template2.yml --stack-name my-stack --region us-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

the second command deletes what the first command deployed to `my-stack`.  I would like to append the resources in `template2.yml` to `my-stack` and keep what was deployed from `template.yml`.  Is there a way to do that? I want the resources in both templates to use the same api gateway endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are technically 2 stacks, but you only gave 1 stack name. So the later command will overwrite the deployed my-stack based on template.yml.

Change your 2nd command to use a different stack name like my-stack2

Comment: resources in different stacks can still talk to each other

Comment: The api gateway resources are being called by a front end application that's expecting a common http endpoint.  If they are 2 stacks can they have the same endpoint?

Comment: If you just want to use the same value of the API gateway endpoint then it is easy, just export that value in your first cloudformation and in your 2nd stack, import that value. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html Otherwise, can you further elaborate on your cloudformation stack and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you @York.  I'll try that.  These two templates I have are just a backend API for a react app.  All of the methods are logically part of a single service so I just want them to all have the same domain name in the http endpoint, with each method only differing by the path after the domain name.

Comment: @gary69 No problem! Looks like export/import is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could deploy this specifications into two different stacks (diferent stack names), besides you could reference the api gateway specification from the first stack into the second stack, this is one way to reference lambda functions in same api gateway.